# Does the amount of solvent affect RATE of solubility?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics

> Example:
>
> Beaker $A$ contains $500$ ml of distilled water. Beaker $B$ contains $1000$ ml of distilled water. $10$  g of salt is added into both beakers.

In this situation, which beaker would the salt dissolve faster in? I am not quite sure if the amount of solute affects rate of solubility.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: No in the specific example and in cases far from saturation. larger systems when one is near saturation I am not sure. Especially without stirring I suspect that a bigger solvent V shortens the time period to dissolve the solute.

Comment: @Alchimista What if both beakers are stirred? (At a constant rate)

Comment: I think that there is not difference. At least not a really observable one

Comment: Is that so? Alrighty. Well thank you for the help! @Alchimista

Comment: I ve anticipated that I am not sure. Try to wait for a more precise answer

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Does-the-solute-dissolve-faster-if-there-is-more-solvent